# How to show that Nearest Neighbour be parallelable?

Tags: nearest-neighbour

I am currently reading nearest Neighbour search problem where given a set of points, preprocess it so that given a query point one can find a nearest neighbor.
There are two phases, preprocessing phase and query phase.

I am trying to design a parallel algorithm for nearest neighbor search problem, but I am confused between two phases written above, preprocessing and query phase.

Should I only design a parallel algorithm for query phase or for both phase? Is there any line of research

Comment: With good algorithms, the queries are fast (like $O(\log(n))$), so there is no room for parallelization of these. Of course you can run several queries in parallel.

Comment: @ 
Yves Daoust Thanks. What do you mean by several queries in parrllel?

Comment: Isn't that obvious ?

Comment: `Nearest Neighbour` in just how many dimensions? By what metric?

Comment: @ Yves Daoust but there are some data structures where the query time is $n^{\Omega (1)}$ (Locality Sensitive Hashing).

Comment: @greybeard High dimensions (theoretically) and I am interested in Euclidian distance.